# Configuring MS forefront for internal network

Tags: microsoft-forefront

This is my first foray into MS Forefront and I'm trying to understand UAG better.

I am running a Windows 8 host with 2 VMs:

VM1 is the domain controller (Windows Server 2012, `IP 5.5.5.5`)
VM2 is the machine with forefront UAG (Windows Server 2008 R2, `IP 5.5.5.25`) - This is connected to the DC

The machines are connected using an internal network and are not configured to be access the internet. Both machine have static IP which I assigned (as per above), and both machines can communicate with each other over ping

I created a HTTP portal through forefront in VM2, and published a file share app in it as well. The portal access is say portal.mytestlab.com

When I try and access `http://portal.mytestlab.com` from the DC (using IE), I get a page not found error. I also tried entering `http://5.5.5.25`, but the same result :(

I know I'm probably doing something stupid, but is there a simple way to enable the portal for my internal network and to see the fileshare after UAG authentication?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the noob question

Comment: 1. Why would you use IPS outside RFC 1918 for a private network?  
2. Have you checked your firewalls?  
3. Are you able to connect to it on the UAG Server?

Comment: I just used those IP's since its easy to remember :). Doesn't matter does it though, its only for my internal network?
I can't even open the site on the UAG server

Comment: I reinstalled UAG and launched the portal from IIS and I can access the portal on the UAG server now. I'll try it from the other computers in my domain and update the post